# Photoshop Brush Only Draws a Point

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Anyone got a quick fix for this?  I've tried everything and am a little stuck right now.  When I use the photoshop brush, it won't draw when I have my mouse clicked down.  It will only do one point and then I have to move somewhere else and do another point.  It only draws in points if that makes sense and I can't extend the point.  Thanks a bunch!

Tyler

Comment: When using my Wacom tablet, I sometimes need to lift the cursor off the tablet, then replace it for brushes to actually do more than paint a single "blob". No clue if you are using a tablet though.

Comment: Ah gotcha!  I’m actually using a mouse unfortunately:/ @Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **Brush Spacing**:

[image]

[image]

Also check all the **Brush Presets** options.

If this doesn't solve the problem, reset Photoshop to its default settings: restart Photoshop pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> Windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> Mac.

Comment: Resetting the settings did it.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: When Photoshop does illogical things, the logic is to go back to its default settings. It doesn't happen so often.